# Apache Flink how to sink from Java ObjectNode -> JSON string?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

So this takes in JSON strings -> Java ObjectNode.

```
    final DataStream<ObjectNode> inputStream = env
        .addSource(new RMQSource<ObjectNode>(
            connectionConfig,                   // config for the RabbitMQ connection
            "start",                            // name of the RabbitMQ queue to consume
            true,                               // use correlation ids; can be false if only at-least-once is required
            new JSONDeserializationSchema()))   // deserialization schema to turn messages into Java objects
        .setParallelism(1);                     // non-parallel source is only required for exactly-once
```

How do I put them back from Java ObjectNode -> JSON string?

```
stream.addSink(new RMQSink<ObjectNode>(
            connectionConfig,
            "stop",
            new JSONSerializationSchema()
        ));
```

`JSONSerializationSchema` doesn't exist but I'd need something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom `SerializationSchema` like this:

```
stream.addSink(new RMQSink<ObjectNode>(
            connectionConfig,
            "stop",
            new SerializationSchema<ObjectNode>() {
                    @Override
                    public byte[] serialize( ObjectNode element ) {
                        return element.toString().getBytes();
                    }
            }
        ));
```